# Is there a way to set 'CallBack' in `jQuery` custom `trigger`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get replay from my `trigger` receiver. using `jQuery` custom `trigger` event. if I am wrong please correct me. If there is a way to do this, Please let me know..

We can set another trigger in receiver, I agree. but can we implement callback?

here is my try:

```
var receiver = function() {    
  console.log('trigger received');
  return "Sending Hellow World!";
}

$(document).on("getReady", receiver);

var triggerer = function() {    
  var callBack = function(msg) {      
    console.log("msg received", msg);
  }

  $(document).trigger("getReady", callBack);
}

triggerer();
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/47je3ekk/)

Comment: This code is very convoluted. What behaviour are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am `return` a value at `receiver` and I would like to hear the same at `callBack` is that possible?

Comment: First of all, you need to describe what you want to happen when you trigger the custom event?

Comment: You can't simply return from a callback if thats the question. It's very hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: You need to receive the evt and the parameter on your receiver function.

Comment: this looks a bit hard to understand at the first sight. But really this question is valid. And reading carefully can help you understand what the OP wants. Should have not been downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use second parameter of `$.trigger`. It should be an **array** of additional parameters that will be passed to your custom event.

That way, you can pass your callback and use it inside `receiver`.

Note that jQuery will **always** pass its own event object as a first parameter to `receiver`.

```js
var receiver = function(e, callback, otherParam){
  console.log('trigger received');
  callback && callback.call(e, "Sending Hello World! " + otherParam);
};

var triggerer = function(){
  var callBack = function(msg) {
    console.log("msg received", msg);
  };
  $(document).trigger("getReady", [callBack, 1337]);
};

$(document).on("getReady", receiver);

triggerer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```